# ChartJS rendering old and new data

Tags: meteor, charts, reactjs

I am creating an application using Meteor and ReactJS.  I have a collection which I subscribe to and the client side, and I want to render a `ChartJS` `Polar Area` chart based on the data from the collection.

The problem is that whenever I update the collection, both the new data and the old data appears on the chart (when I hover, I get two different values for the segments, the old data and the new data).

Here is my code:

```
ChartComponent = React.createClass({

    mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

    getMeteordata() {
      let data = Meteor.subscribe("sentiment");
      return {
        chartData: [
          {
            value: MyCollection.find({"item": "test1"}).count(),
            color: "green",
            label: "Test1"
          },
          {
            value: MyCollection.find({"item": "test2"}).count(),
            color: "yellow",
            label: "Test2"
          },
          {
            value: MyCollection.find({"item": "test3"}).count(),
            color: "red",
            label: "Test3"
          } 
        ]
      }
    },

    _drawGraph() {
      let ctx = document.getElementById("my-canvas").getContext("2d");
      let polarChart = new Chart(ctx).Polararea(this.data.chartData, {
         animateScale: true,
      });

      return polarChart;
    },


    componentDidMount() {
      this._drawGraph();
    },


    componentDidUpdate() {
      this._drawGraph().update();
    },


    render() {
      return <canvas id="my-canvas"></canvas>
    }
});
```

Help would be appreciated.  Thank you very much!

**Note:**

I am using react version 0.14.  The official react-chartjs component does not work, due to some of the api changes.

Comment: The chart is actually still there though, you should be destroying your previous chart before initializing your new one.

Comment: @BenM calling `this._drawGraph().destroy()` before `this._drawGraph().update()` has no effect.

Comment: `this._drawGraph()` is returning a new chart object each time. You will need to keep track of the return value and then destroy that return value as that is the currently implemented chart.

Comment: @BenM I'm sorry I'm a bit new to this.  How might I go about doing that?

Comment: Since a change in the value somewhat causes a change in the render output, you could put it in the state. But because this is kind of a sidestep of react you could just place it in an instance variable. So something like `...createClass({ chart: null ...` then in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` you can do `this.chart = _this.drawGraph()`. In `_drawGraph` you would check if `this.chart` is not `null` if so then call `this.chart.destroy()`.

Comment: @BenM Thank you very much for your help! It works now :)